# emacsclient, restore all windows in a frame in terminal

Tags: terminal, emacs, window, frame

The object: In terminal, on start, in one frame, restore emacs workspace. i.e. restore all "windows", to the state before C-x C-c.

Descriptions: The window restoration could be simply done in emacs GUI, by adding `(desktop-save-mode 1)`  to the init.el file.

However, when running emacs as a Daemon, emacsclient does not perform the same way. With the same setup, it still remember the major mode of the file, as well as other buffers before exiting, but the **window layout** will not be restored. Only 1 major window is displayed depend on the default settings.

I did some research, poked into some functions/variables using the elisp build-in documentation. I checked `(desktop-save-buffer 1)`, `framset-save`, `framset-restore`  and none of them seems to work. Also I checked similar questions posted before, and I found someone's answer using the following script:

```
 (setq desktop-restore-forces-onscreen nil)
    (add-hook 'desktop-after-read-hook
     (lambda ()
       (frameset-restore
        desktop-saved-frameset
        :reuse-frames (eq desktop-restore-reuses-frames t)
        :cleanup-frames (not (eq desktop-restore-reuses-frames 'keep))
        :force-display desktop-restore-in-current-display
        :force-onscreen desktop-restore-forces-onscreen)))
```

However this script is buggy, it opens a "GUI" frame, and could not be closed properly(reopen automatically whenever closed, and if possible, I prefer to open the frame in terminal, so that a terminal 'texteditor' setting is possibe, with some other minor merits).
  Sorry for the tedious question, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the right way to do this, but I was able to restore a frameset created in a GUI frame into a terminal frame.  The new frame must be big enough or it will throw an error.  I did `(setq foo (frameset-save (frame-list)))` and `(pp foo (get-buffer "*scratch*"))` to dump a `read`able representation of the frameset to the `*scratch*` buffer.  Then I edited it by hand to get rid of `(display . ":0.0")`.  That seemed to be enough to get it to not force a GUI frame.  Then I did `(frameset-restore [frameset ...])` on the edited frameset.

If you look at `frameset.el`, there are filtering functions to edit a frameset programmatically.  Also, if you look at the comments, the `display` parameter is treated specially.  You should look at the details there.